# Production Planning & Leave Tracking Calculator

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Guys,
I'm super stumped.

I am in project management.
I am currently using Excel Web App, which is browser based.

I have 2 Excel Workbooks.

Workbook 1 is titled "**Production Planning 1**". I use this workbook to check how many Man Days (Workable Days) an employee can add to a Project, where the Project has a "Start Date" and an "End Date".

In the **Production Planning 1 workbook**, on the **Production Planning worksheet**, the user can input the "Start Date" and "End Date" in C4 and D4 respectively.

Using NETWORKDAYS.INTL, you can see that the number of Man Days and Man Hours calculated are as shown in F4 and G4 respectively (Man Hours is just x 8 of Man Days)

That's all fine and dandy.
But now I want to tabulate that particular employee's Leave Days between the "Start Date" and "End Date".

The user keys in "James Ferrell" in C11.There will be a formula in D11 which pulls up all the Leave Days for employee "James Ferrell" between the "Start Date" and "End Date"

Cell E11 is just Man Days minus Leave Days ( F4 - D11). (Man Days now adjusted for Leave Days)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBQWq.jpg)

The Leave Days for every employee in the company is recorded in:
Workbook 2, titled **"Leave Tracker".**

Here, you can see that the Dates are B1:T1
There are currently 2 types of Leave Days: Unpaid Leave (UL) and Paid Leave (PL).

So, if the user keys in "James Ferrell" in cell C11 in the Production Planning 1 workbook, then in the same workbook, the formula in cells D11 should pull up the combined instances of UL + PL from the Leave Tracker workbook for "James Ferrell".

For example, if the "Start Date" and "End Date" are as per** Production Planning 1 workbook**, 1 April 2023, and 18 April 2023, respectively, then we can see in the Leave Tracker workbook that between those dates, "James Ferrell" has 2 Leave Days (1 UL + 1 PL).

Therefore, in cell D11 in the **Production Planning 1 workbook**, the formula should spit out "2".

I don't really care about knowing what type of Leave Days "James Ferrell" has within that date range, just the total number of Leave Days. (although if separating them into how many days of UL he has, how many days of PL he has makes the formula easier, I'm up for that as well)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlPOi.jpg)

I'm an Excel novice, so I can't seem to find the right formula for Cell D11 in the Production Planning 1 Workbook.

So far, all the formulas I've tried seem to break (#Value).

The only key-able, input-table cells the user in this scenario has access to are in the Production Planning 1 Workbook:
C4 and D4 (Start Date, End Date)
C11, C12, C13 (Employee Name 1, Employee Name 2, Employee Name 3)

I'm super stumped and really not sure where to go from here, tearing my hair out and all.

I tried SUMPRODUCTS but I keep on getting a REF error.

Comment: Something like countif(B1:T1,"*L)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Countif` combined with `Indirect`, `Address` and `Match`

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH($B7,$A$1:$A$4,0),MATCH($B$5,$A$1:$T$1,0),1) & ":" & ADDRESS(MATCH($B7,$A$1:$A$4,0),MATCH($C$5,$A$1:$T$1,0),1),TRUE),"*L")
```

[image]

The breakdown:

- `Countif([range],[criteria])` - should be quite self-explanatory
- `Indirect([text to convert to actual address that can be used by the formula])`
- `Address([Row], [column], [absolute/reference])`

  - `Match([lookup value], [lookup range], [lookup type])` - returns the row number or the column number, depending on what we're looking for
  - In the first and third `Match`, we're looking for what row the Employee is on
  - In the second `Match`, we're looking for what column the **start** date is on
  - In the fourth `Match`, we're looking for what column the **end** date is on
  - We have a second `Address` formula here that's concantenated by `& ":" &` so that we can have a proper range to return to the `Indirect` formula. `eg. $B$2:$S$2`

With that formula you should be able to just drag it down through all the employees